# Software to auto correct lens distortion based on photo

Tags: lens, photo-editing, windows, distortion

A photo contains digital information about the make of the camera the focal length,etc. Does any software use this information and auto correct the lens distortion in the photo. I know that Photoshop CS5 does have an auto feature but the list of camera's in the auto mode are few.

Are there any specialized software that can analyse the photo and do the same without user intervention. I currently own a Windows computer.

Comment: You can create your own lens profiles for Photoshop (& Lightroom) with Adobe's free Lens Profile Creator: http://labs.adobe.com/technologies/lensprofile_creator/

Answer (score 7):

Lightroom does this for selected lenses, or you can create your own profile if your lens isn't listed.

[This blog post](http://mansurovs.com/lightroom-3-lens-correction) explains how this works, both with respect to the built-in profiles, adjusting manually, or creating your own with Adobe's software utility.

Answer (score 3):

One that I know of is [DxO Optics Pro](http://www.dxo.com/intl/photo/dxo_optics_pro/introduction).  I've used the trial version of this software, and it seems pretty good.  Not quite enough additional value for me to get this on top of PSE at this point, but I was considering it instead of PSE for a while.

Comment: +1 I've used it, good results, doesn't integrate very well with Aperture though, which I use as a library.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a Canon camera, their DPP software that comes bundled with the camera does this. I believe Nikon's equivalent can, too, but this software must be bought separately.

Comment: well I currently have a sony camera its a point and shoot consumer camera

Answer (score 2):

[PTLens](http://epaperpress.com/ptlens/) is software that corrects lens pincushion/barrel distortion, vignetting, chromatic aberration, and perspective. This is an amazing little software it removes the distortion automatically you don't have to add your camera/lens profiles.

Just adding to this list (*a software that I came across while randomly searching Google*) although I'm yet auditioning most of these amazing suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

[Lensfun](http://lensfun.berlios.de/) claims to be such a free software but it has a beta version only. You may also use this software as:

- [ufraw](http://ufraw.sourceforge.net/) plugin ( they not suggest this for Windows)
- [GimpLensFun](http://lensfun.sebastiankraft.net/) gimp plugin.

Comment: Note that lensfun is *primarily* a library for software developers to use so they can add this kind of capability to their software.  A command-line utility is included, but it's really intended as a demo of the library, not the primary use of the code.

Answer (score 1):

**Non-automatic**. Hugin can be used to find out the parameters for lens-correction. See here:

- [Tutorial Hugin Lens Calibration](http://hugin.sourceforge.net/tutorials/calibration/en.shtml)
- [HowTo for obtaining lens parameters step by step for DIY Streetview](http://www.diy-streetview.org/how-to-lens-parameters/)

Of course, once obtained for a lens, the parameters stay the same and simply be loaded into hugin.

Answer (score 0):

First, a few more possibilities: Bibble Pro and Capture One Pro both also include lens correction capabilities. C1P supports manual adjustment (and/or fine tuning) in addition to automatic correction based on a lens profile. Bibble uses only the lens profile, so your choices are automatic correction, or none at all.

It's also worth noting that there are some fairly substantial differences in how much different programs automate the process. For example, with a zoom lens the distortion almost always changes depending on the focal length. Adobe's correction doesn't detect when the focal length has changed, so when you pick a correction for a particular lens, they will continue to use that correction even if the focal length changes (and with it the distortion). Bibble and PTLens (for a couple of examples) handle this better -- they'll take both the lens *and* the current focal length into account automatically.

Answer (score 0):

[Darktable](http://darktable.org) can do what you want, and since your question is rather old, I dare to recommend it although it runs only on Linux and Mac.  It uses the [Lensfun](http://lensfun.sf.net) library, which covers more than 500 lenses so far.  If your lens is not included yet, you can [upload RAW pictures](http://wilson.bronger.org/calibration) and let the Lensfun people do the rest.