# What is the best lens correction software which integrates with Aperture 3?

Tags: lens, software, photo-editing, apple-aperture, plugin

I want to know if there are any good lens correction software (i.e. plugin) for Aperture 3? I am primarily looking for general purpose lens correction software.

I have looked at the plugin page for Aperture 3, but this does not give a clue which is the best. I have also searched the Internet, but there are not many reviews when it comes to this kind of software.

However what is best might be subjective, but I hope that you could give me the pros and cons of the one that you suggest. I am also interested in your experience with the software.

Some interesting things to know (handy but not necessary):

- Why is it so good?
- Is it easy to use?
- Is it well integrated with Aperture 3?
- How is the customer support?

Comment: I know that there is a similar question, but that is not specific to Aperture 3 and is not targeting Mac OS X. [link](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/8589/software-to-auto-correct-lens-distortion-based-on-photo)

Comment: I am a fan of PTLens.

Comment: Could please elaborate on this? What makes PTLens so good? Is it easy to use? Is it well integrated with Aperture 3? How is the end result?

Comment: I don't have or use Aperture 3. I just use PTLens standalone, and have read that it is an available plugin for Aperture. That is why I didn't write a full answer, because you would have to look into it yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer partly depends on what you are trying to correct; for correcting fisheye-style wide angle lens distortion I really like a program called Fisheye-Hemi:

http://www.imagetrendsinc.com/products/prodpage_hemi.asp

That has just a few settings, but does a nice job making fisheye images look more natural.

Between the three general-purpose lens correction plugins listed (FixLens, LensFix, and PTLens) I'm not sure which is best - PTLens is more classic but traditionally had a rather complex interface, FixLens and LensFix may be simpler to use.

Edit:

Looking at the release dates, FixLens from Human Software was last updated in 2010 - the other two, in 2008!  Also the screenshots make FixLens look more advanced... I would go for FixLens for a general purpose tool.

Comment: I was looking for a general purpose lens correction.

Comment: The LensFix application currently has no support (as of 1 January 2012). According to the homepage the support will be back in July 2012. So it seems that this is a bit insecure and is out of the picture right now.

Answer (score 1):

Whilst this is not really answering the exact question because it is not a plugin for Aperture (and perhaps I will get some downgrades?) I could highly recommend [DxO Optics](http://www.dxo.com/uk/photo/dxo_optics_pro/introduction) for your needs.

This is a leader in lens correction and workflow software. It has a huge range of Camera/Lens combinations that it is able to correct for optical distortion, vignetting, exposure, noise, and more.

They also do a [Film Pack](http://www.dxo.com/uk/photo/filmpack) which can be purchased as a plugin for Aperture (and others) which allows you to apply film effects to digital photos.

I can't really comment on customer support as I've never needed to use them.  But regarding the crux of your question - lens correction software - this really can't be beaten.

There's a review of DxO [here](http://blogcritics.org/scitech/article/software-review-dxo-optics-pro-7/) and [here](http://corrosphotoblog.blogspot.com/2011/12/review-dxo-optics-pro-7.html).
You can download a trial version [here](http://www.dxo.com/uk/photo/free_trial_version).

Comment: I am really looking for something that integrates well with Aperture 3, although DxO optics seems to be a good choice for lens correction software. However I cannot see how I could integrate this into my workflow when using Aperture 3. But if there is a good way to integrate it with my workflow, please let me know. Maybe I am missing something here.

Comment: As I said before - I knew when I posted it, it wasn't exactly what you were looking for as it wasn't a plugin, but at least it gives you options :)

Comment: Thanks for giving me the option! It was not my intention to ungrateful.

Answer (score 1):

My favorite is [Lensfix](http://www.kekus.com/lensfix.html), definitely better. It corrects RAW, the other don´t. But currently it is temporarily [out of production](http://www.kekus.com/buy.html)

> Important News:  As of 1 January 2012 Kekus will no longer sell Calico
>   or LensFix in order to care for a family member.  I hope to return to
>   active development in July.  In the mean time, I will provide limited
>   support and keep the download live for existing customers